# 400 Bad Request when add contact to Yahoo! Messenger

Tags: vb.net, yahoo, yahoo-api

I want to add contact to yahoo messenger using [Api](https://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/ch02s03.html) with VB NET.

this is my code:

```
Dim url As String = "http://developer.messenger.yahooapis.com/v1/group/{{GROUP}}/contact/yahoo/{{USER}}"
    url &= "?oauth_consumer_key=" & sConsumer_key
    url &= "&oauth_nonce=" & GetRandom(10000, 50000)
    url &= "&oauth_signature=" & sConsumer_secret & "%26" & oauth_token_secret_value
    url &= "&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT"
    url &= "&oauth_timestamp=" & TimeOfDay
    url &= "&oauth_token=" & oauth_token_value
    url &= "&oauth_version=1.0"
    url &= "&sid=" & YmsgSessionID

    url = Replace(url, "{{GROUP}}", group)
    url = Replace(url, "{{USER}}", user)

    '//additional header
    Dim request As WebRequest = Nothing
    Dim webAddress As Uri
    webAddress = New Uri(url)

    ' Create the web request  
    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(webAddress), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim myheaders As WebHeaderCollection

    ' set type to GET
    request.Method = "PUT"
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    myheaders = request.Headers
    myheaders.Add("charset", "utf-8")

    '----- get response
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

When I execute it I got an exception 400 bad request at:

`Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()`.

I have try to use the same url with DELETE method (`request.Method="DELETE"`) and it works, but when I change to PUT method, i get 400 bad request. Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using PUT instead of GET? Are you trying to upload a file?

Comment: Based on this [Group Contact Management Api](https://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/ch02s03.html) , there are only PUT and DELETE operation for this url. I have tried to use GET and it says Method not allowed.